# Fazer o cáculo e mostrar a Matriz em C (dev c++)

Tags: c, algoritmo

Tenho que fazer isso:

> Faça um programa que carregue uma matriz 12x4 com os valores das
>   vendas de uma loja, onde cada linha representa um mês do ano e cada
>   coluna representa uma semana do mês. Calcule e mostre;
>
> - o total vendido em cada mês do ano, mostrando o nome do mês por extenso;
> - o total vendido em cada semana durante todo o ano;
> - o total vendido pela loja no ano.

O total do ano deu certo, mas os outros dois resultados não consigo, os número não aparecem certo. Eu realmente não sei como proceder :(

Esse é o meu código:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <locale.h>
```

```
int main ()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "PORTUGUESE");
```

`int mat[12][4], l, c, totalsemana, totalano, jan, fev, mar, abr, mai, jun, jul, ago, set, out, nov, dez;
char mes;

//PEDIR VALORES
for(l=0; l<12; l++)
{
    for(c=0; c<4; c++)
    {
        printf("\n________________________________________________________________");
        printf("\n\n Insira o valor das vendas do mês %i - semana %i - posição [%i][%i]: ", l+1, c+1, l+1, c+1);
        scanf("%i", &mat[l][c]);

        totalano = totalano + mat[l][c];
    }
}

for(l=0; l<12; l++)
{
    for(c=0; c<4; c++)
    {   
        jan = jan + mat[1][c]; 
        fev = fev + mat[2][c];
        mar = mar + mat[3][c];
        abr = abr + mat[4][c];
        mai = mai + mat[5][c];
        jun = jun + mat[6][c];
        jul = jul + mat[7][c];
        ago = ago + mat[8][c];
        set = set + mat[9][c];
        out = out + mat[10][c];
        nov = nov + mat[11][c];
        dez = dez + mat[12][c];
    }
}


printf("\n\n ################### R E S U L T A D O S #####################");

printf("\n\n ****************************************************");
printf("\n\n   O total vendido no ANO é: %i", totalano);


//MOSTRAR EM CADA SEMANA
printf("\n\n ****************************************************");
printf("\n\n O total vendido em cada SEMANA é: ");
for(c=0; c<4; c++)
{
    for(l=0; l<12; l++)
    {       
        printf("\n------------------------------------");
        printf("\n Mês %i - semana %i: ", l+1, c+1);
        printf("%i", mat[l][4]);
    }
}

printf("\n\n ****************************************************");

//MOSTRAR CADA MES
printf("\n\n O total de venda em cada MÊS no ano é: ");
printf("\n Janeiro: %i", jan);
printf("\n Fevereiro: %i", fev);
printf("\n Março: %i", mar);
printf("\n Abril: %i", abr);
printf("\n Maio: %i", mai);
printf("\n Junho: %i", jun);
printf("\n Julho: %i", jul);
printf("\n Agosto: %i", ago);
printf("\n Setembro: %i", set);
printf("\n Outubro: %i", out);
printf("\n Novembro: %i", nov);
printf("\n Dezembro: %i", dez);

printf("\n\n ****************************************************");

}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei vários erros no seu código, aqui estão eles:
Primeiro, as variáveis onde você está guardando o valor arrecadado em cada mês precisam ser inicializar, dessa forma:

```
int mat[12][4], l, c, totalsemana, totalano, jan = 0, fev = 0, mar = 0, abr = 0, mai = 0, jun = 0, jul = 0, ago = 0, set = 0, out = 0, nov = 0, dez = 0;
```

Segundo, o seu segundo laço está errado, aqui está ele:

```
//for(l=0; l<12; l++){
    for(c=0; c<4; c++){   
        jan += mat[1][c]; 
        fev += mat[2][c];
        mar += mat[3][c];
        abr += mat[4][c];
        mai += mat[5][c];
        jun += mat[6][c];
        jul += mat[7][c];
        ago += mat[8][c];
        set += mat[9][c];
        out += mat[10][c];
        nov += mat[11][c];
        dez += mat[12][c];
    }
//}
```

e por último, o a sua indexação no laço que mostra cada semana está incorreto, aqui está como ela deveria ficar:

```
printf("\n------------------------------------");
printf("\n Mês %i - semana %i: ", l+1, c+1);
printf("%i", mat[l][c]);
```

Uma dica: indente bem seu código, isso auxilia a manutenção dele e a leitura por terceiros.